# How many possible file types in the output `ls -l` command?

Tags: ls, file-types

usually, the possible file types in the output `ls -l` command are `d` and `-`, which represent directory and regular file respectively.

besides above, I saw another type `l` in the output on macOS.

```
drwxr-xr-x   8 yongjia  staff    256 Aug 31 06:58 .
drwxr-xr-x   4 yongjia  staff    128 Aug 30 11:31 ..
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root     wheel      1 Aug 17 07:25 Macintosh HD -> /
```

So, How many possible file types in the output `ls -l` command?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The filetypes reported by `ls` depends on the capabilities of the underlying filesystem, the operating system, and on the specific implementation of `ls`.

The `l` type is the common *symbolic link* file type.

This is (ought to be) documented in your `ls` manual.

On OpenBSD (macOS and AIX has the same list, but in another order):

```
-     regular file
b     block special file
c     character special file
d     directory
l     symbolic link
p     FIFO
s     socket link
```

On NetBSD (FreeBSD has the same without `a` and `A`):

```
-     Regular file.
a     Archive state 1.
A     Archive state 2.
b     Block special file.
c     Character special file.
d     Directory.
l     Symbolic link.
p     FIFO.
s     Socket link.
w     Whiteout.
```

From `info ls` (i.e. the GNU `ls` manual):

```
‘-’
     regular file
‘b’
     block special file
‘c’
     character special file
‘C’
     high performance (“contiguous data”) file
‘d’
     directory
‘D’
     door (Solaris 2.5 and up)
‘l’
     symbolic link
‘M’
     off-line (“migrated”) file (Cray DMF)
‘n’
     network special file (HP-UX)
‘p’
     FIFO (named pipe)
‘P’
     port (Solaris 10 and up)
‘s’
     socket
‘?’
     some other file type
```

On Solaris 11:

```
d
The entry is a directory.

D
The entry is a door.

l
The entry is a symbolic link.

b
The entry is a block special file.

c
The entry is a character special file.

p
The entry is a FIFO (or “named pipe”) special file.

P
The entry is an event port.

s
The entry is an AF_UNIX address family socket.

-
The entry is an ordinary file.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find that information in the `info` pages by doing `info coreutils 'ls invocation'`.  On my system it includes the following excerpt:

```
 The file type is one of the following characters:

`-'
      regular file

`b'
      block special file

`c'
      character special file

`C'
      high performance ("contiguous data") file

`d'
      directory

`D'
      door (Solaris 2.5 and up)

`l'
      symbolic link

`M'
      off-line ("migrated") file (Cray DMF)

`n'
      network special file (HP-UX)

`p'
      FIFO (named pipe)

`P'
      port (Solaris 10 and up)

`s'
      socket

`?'
      some other file type
```