# nl: How to start line numbers on the second line?

Tags: ls, nl

This is the standard output of `ls -ln | nl`

```
wolf@linux:~$ ls -lh | nl
     1  total 24
     2  -rw-rw-r-- 1 wolf wolf  186 Sep  24 22:18 01.py
     3  -rw-rw-r-- 1 wolf wolf  585 Sep  24 22:21 02.py
     4  -rw-rw-r-- 1 wolf wolf  933 Sep  24 22:26 03.py
wolf@linux:~$
```

Instead of starting the number from `total 24`, would it be possible to start it from the actual files/directory which is the second line?

Desired output

```
wolf@linux:~$ ls -lh | nl
        total 24
     1  -rw-rw-r-- 1 wolf wolf  186 Sep  24 22:18 01.py
     2  -rw-rw-r-- 1 wolf wolf  585 Sep  24 22:21 02.py
     3  -rw-rw-r-- 1 wolf wolf  933 Sep  24 22:26 03.py
wolf@linux:~$
```

Answer (score 15):

#### Consume the first line with something else and pass the rest to `nl`

```
$ ls -lh | { sed -u q; nl; }
total 24
     1  -rw-rw-r-- 1 wolf wolf  186 Sep  24 22:18 01.py
     2  -rw-rw-r-- 1 wolf wolf  585 Sep  24 22:21 02.py
     3  -rw-rw-r-- 1 wolf wolf  933 Sep  24 22:26 03.py
```

`sed` (with `-u` to disable buffering), will consume one line and `q`uit, implicitly printing the line before termination. `nl` consumes the rest of the lines.

If you really want the first line indented, you can do it like this:

```
$ ls -lh | { sed -u 's/^/        /;q'; nl; }
        total 24
     1  -rw-rw-r-- 1 wolf wolf  186 Sep  24 22:18 01.py
     2  -rw-rw-r-- 1 wolf wolf  585 Sep  24 22:21 02.py
     3  -rw-rw-r-- 1 wolf wolf  933 Sep  24 22:26 03.py
```

If you want to start the line numbering further down, tell `sed` when to `q`uit:

```
$ ls -alh | { sed -u 's/^/        /;3q'; nl; }
        total 24
        drwx------ 1 wolf wolf  186 Sep  24 22:18 .
        drwx------ 1 wolf wolf  186 Sep  24 22:18 ..
     1  -rw-rw-r-- 1 wolf wolf  186 Sep  24 22:18 01.py
     2  -rw-rw-r-- 1 wolf wolf  585 Sep  24 22:21 02.py
     3  -rw-rw-r-- 1 wolf wolf  933 Sep  24 22:26 03.py
```

You could also use something like `/\.\.$/q` instead of `3q`.

Comment: `ls -lh | tail -n +2 | nl` would probably be cleaner.

Comment: @Ángel You lose the first line, though, and I think preserving it while not including it in the line numbering is the main point of this question.

Answer (score 14):

This will make `nl` start from 0 :

```
$ ls -lh | nl -v 0
   0  total 24
   1  -rw-rw-r-- 1 wolf wolf  186 Sep  24 22:18 01.py
   2  -rw-rw-r-- 1 wolf wolf  585 Sep  24 22:21 02.py
   3  -rw-rw-r-- 1 wolf wolf  933 Sep  24 22:26 03.py
```

Answer (score 7):

It's kind of ugly, but at least with the GNU Coreutils implementation of `nl` you can specify the lines to be numbered via a regular expression - since `t` is not one of the possible file types in the `ls` long-list output<sup>[1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/538419/how-many-possible-file-types-in-the-output-ls-l-command)</sup> you could do

```
ls -lh | nl -bp'^[^t]'
```

Unfortunately this does not preserve the output alignment though.

Perhaps the most formally correct approach is to separate the `ls` output into distinct header and body sections:

```
$ ls -lh | sed -e '1s/.*/\\:\\:\\:\n&\n\\:\\:/' | nl

       total 0

     1  -rw-rw-rw- 1 steeldriver steeldriver   0 Sep  9 19:53 bar
     2  -rw-r--r-- 1 steeldriver steeldriver 449 Sep 16 17:41 bash_envs
     3  -rw-rw-rw- 1 steeldriver steeldriver 131 Sep  5 18:13 dirlist
     4  -rw-r--r-- 1 steeldriver steeldriver 359 Sep 13 19:42 error_status
```

(by default, header numbering style is *none*).

Comment: The alignment can be preserved if a sufficient number width is specified, e.g., `ls -lh | nl -w4 -bp'^[^t]'`.

Comment: You'll still have a problem if some filenames or symlink targets contain `\nt` or `nl`'s special delimiters.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: `ls --hide-control-chars` might be a good idea for this listing.  Or one of the `-Q` quoting options to otherwise avoid printing a literal newline as part of the filename.  Presumably the desired result with numbered lines is one file per line, so newlines in filenames would break that.  (And/or not numbering "continuation" lines might be *desired*, if there was a reliable way to make that happen.)

Answer (score 6):

You could try it with `awk` instead:

```
ls -lh | awk '{printf("%5s  ",NR==1?" ":NR-1); print}'
```

This will print the "totals" line without numbering it, and all remaining lines with numbers, right-adjusted, with a field width of 5. The space between number and line content will be two spaces (the text after the `5s` in the `printf()` format string); you can replace it with something else such as `\t`.

If you don't need the "totals" line, you can use

```
ls -lh | awk 'NR>1{print (NR-1) "\t" $0}'
```

or

```
ls -lh | awk 'NR>1 {printf("%5s  ",NR-1); print}'
```

instead.

Comment: ... and once again, it would be nice to understand what is wrong with the answer that merits a down-vote ...